# Using Database to add Data to ListView

Tags: android

Having difficulty with this. I'm wanting to use a database to get data from the Add Reminder page to the Reminder page which contains a list view.

This is the database file

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MOSDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ReminderTable";


    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            "PTITLE" + " TEXT ," + //HEADING FOR MINUTE SELECTED IN TIMEPICKER
            "PA" + " TEXT ," + //PAYMENT VALUE
            "PDAY" + " TEXT ," + //DAY SELECTED IN DATEPICKER
            "PMONTH" + " TEXT ," + //MONTH SELECTED IN DATEPICKER
            "PYEAR" + " TEXT ," + //YEAR SELECTED IN DATEPICKER
            "RDAY" + " TEXT ," + //REMINDER DAY
            "RMONTH" + " TEXT ," + //REMINDER MONTH
            "RYEAR" + " TEXT ," + //REMINDER YEAR
            "RMIN" + " TEXT ," + //REMINDER MIN
            "RHOUR" + " TEXT);"; //REMINDER HOUR

    MOSDatabase(Context context){
        super(context, "MOSDatabase", null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }


}
```

This is the CustomAdapter used in my Reminder page

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    Cursor C;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    String color;
    String text_color;
    String bgcolor;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public ArrayList<String> paymentTitle;
    public ArrayList<String> paymentDate;
    public ArrayList<String> reminderTime;
    public ArrayList<String> reminderDate;
    public ArrayList<String> paymentAmount;


   // Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Roboto-Light.ttf");


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> pt, ArrayList<String> pd, ArrayList<String> rd, ArrayList<String> rt, ArrayList<String> pa) {

        super(context, resource, pt);

        this.paymentTitle = pt;
        this.paymentDate = pd;
        this.reminderDate = rd;
        this.reminderTime = rt;
        this.paymentAmount = pa;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

        }

        //Get the corresponding string for the position of arraylist
        String paymentTimeStr = paymentTitle.get(position).toString();
        String paymentDateStr = paymentDate.get(position).toString();
        String reminderDateStr = reminderDate.get(position).toString();
        String reminderTimeStr = reminderTime.get(position).toString();
        String paymentValueStr = paymentAmount.get(position).toString();


        //FIND THE TEXTVIEWS FROM YOUR INDIVIDUAL LAYOUT
        TextView payDateTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtPaymentDate);
        TextView payTitleTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView reminderDateTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtReminderDate);
        TextView reminderTimeTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtReminderTime);
        TextView paymentValueTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);


        if (payDateTV != null) {
            payDateTV.setText(paymentDateStr);
        }

        if (payTitleTV != null) {
            payTitleTV.setText(paymentTimeStr);
        }

        if (reminderDateTV != null) {
            reminderDateTV.setText(reminderDateStr);
        }

        if (reminderTimeTV != null) {
            reminderTimeTV.setText(reminderTimeStr);
        }

        if (paymentValueTV != null) {
            paymentValueTV.setText(paymentValueStr);
        }

        return v;

    }
}
```

This is the Reminder page

```
public class Reminders extends Activity
{
    TextView title;
    Button add, edit, remove;
    ListView mListView;

    ArrayList<String> paymentTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> paymentDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> reminderDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> reminderTime = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> paymentVal = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminders);
        initializeVariables();

        MOSDatabase mDatabase = new MOSDatabase(this);

        //DEFINE CUSTOM ADAPTER
        CustomAdapter aa = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.item_row, paymentTitle, paymentDate, reminderDate, reminderTime, paymentVal);

        //SET CUSTOM ADAPTER FOR LISTVIEW
        mListView.setAdapter(aa);

        // READING A DB
        SQLiteDatabase readableDB = mDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor C = readableDB.query("ReminderTable", new String[] { "PTITLE", "PA", "PDAY", "PMONTH", "PYEAR", "RDAY", "RMONTH",
                "RYEAR", "RMIN", "RHOUR" }, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (C == null)
        {
            title.setText("No Upcoming Payments");
        }
        else{
            C.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String reminderDateStr = "";
                String reminderTimeStr = "";
                String paymentDateStr = "";
                String paymentTitleStr = "";
                String paymentValue = "";

                //Build strings of each record to then be set to the listview
                reminderDateStr = C.getString(5) + "/" + C.getString(6)+ "/" +C.getString(7);
                reminderTimeStr = C.getString(8) + ":" + C.getString(9);
                paymentDateStr = C.getString(2) + "/" + C.getString(3) + "/" + C.getString(4);
                paymentTitleStr = C.getString(0);
                paymentValue = C.getString(1);

                //Add the new strings to the corresponding array
                paymentTitle.add(paymentTitleStr);
                reminderTime.add(reminderTimeStr);
                paymentDate.add(paymentDateStr);
                reminderDate.add(reminderDateStr);
                paymentVal.add(paymentValue);

            } while (C.moveToNext());
        }



        //CLOSE CURSOR AND DATABASE TO AVOID MEMORY LEAKS
        C.close();
        readableDB.close();

        //TELL ADAPTER THERE IS NEW DATA SO UPDATE THE LISTVIEW ACCORDINGLY
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    private void initializeVariables()
    {
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEdit);
        remove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRemove);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LVReminder);
    }

    public void addClicked(View view)
    {
        Intent openNewPayment = new Intent("com.studentbudget.ADDREMINDER");
        startActivity(openNewPayment);
        finish();
    }
}
```

When I ran my application and clicked on the Reminder link, it didn't open and crashed. This is the logcat:

```
08-04 23:02:59.798  10548-10548/com.studentbudget E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.studentbudget/com.studentbudget.Reminders}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
        at com.studentbudget.Reminders.onCreate(Reminders.java:66)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        ... 11 more
```

Line 66 is this:

```
reminderDateStr = C.getString(5) + "/" + C.getString(6)+ "/" +C.getString(7);
```

I've tried changing it so it was reminderDateStr = "Test"; and it worked so there's something wrong with the C.getString(num) method and I don't know what it is.

Thanks to anyone who helps me get this fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C.moveToFirst()` returns `false` if there is no entry in the cursor. Check it because this will cause an `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` if there is no entry.

Also always check if there is the row and get the right cursor index like `C.getColumnIndex("RDAY")`

```
if(C.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String reminderDateStr = "";
        String reminderTimeStr = "";
        String paymentDateStr = "";
        String paymentTitleStr = "";
        String paymentValue = "";

        //Build strings of each record to then be set to the listview
        reminderDateStr = C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("RDAY")) + "/" + C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("RMONTH"))+ "/" +C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("RYEAR"));
        reminderTimeStr = C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("RHOUR")) + ":" + C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("RMIN"));
        paymentDateStr = C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("PDAY")) + "/" + C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("PMONTH")) + "/" + C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("PYEAR"));
        paymentTitleStr = C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("PTITLE"));
        paymentValue = C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("PA"));

        //Add the new strings to the corresponding array
        paymentTitle.add(paymentTitleStr);
        reminderTime.add(reminderTimeStr);
        paymentDate.add(paymentDateStr);
        reminderDate.add(reminderDateStr);
        paymentVal.add(paymentValue);

    } while (C.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
reminderDateStr = C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("RDAY")) + "/" +
                  C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("RMONTH"))+ "/" + 
                  C.getString(C.getColumnIndex("RYEAR"));
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably this line:

```
C.moveToFirst();
```

combined with

```
while (C.moveToNext());
```

Using these two lines will end up in incrementing beyond the scope of the Cursor.

Instead of doing that, simply use

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    // Retrieve data here
}

c.close();
```

Comment: Didn't work, it keeps saying there's an error on the same line

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a 0 size cursor and you try to read it. I suggest changing your cursor reading code to:

```
if (C == null || !C.moveToFirst())
    {
        title.setText("No Upcoming Payments");
    }
    else{
        do {
            String reminderDateStr = "";
            ...
            //Build strings of each record to then be set to the listview
            ...
            //Add the new strings to the corresponding array
       } while (C.moveToNext());
    }
```